# Emulate Ethernet between two USB-C ports

Tags: linux, ethernet, usb-c

I have 3 low-end servers with only one ethernet port each that I use for Internet connection. Now I would like to have a second Ethernet interface to each 3 servers to a file server so that reading and writing to the file server would not impact the network connection.

An idea would be to use a separate ethernet switch and USB-C to Ethernet adapters for every server. However it feels like an awful waste of hardware and also complicated.

Would it be possible to connect a USB-C cable directly from each of the low-end servers to the file server and have the file server emulate Ethernet over USB?

I am planning to install Linux on the file server.

Comment: You first need to determine if these "*low-end servers*" have Dual-Role Ports. See https://superuser.com/questions/1140136/how-does-usb-c-affect-usbs-distinction-between-host-and-peripheral But since you consider USB-to-Ethernet adapters "*complicated*", you might want to reconsider using dual network interfaces.